# DatePicker in WPF showing 01.01.0001 instead of today

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, wpf-controls

I was trying to set todays date in my datepicker:

```
<DatePicker Height="25" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 0 0 0" Name="BornDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Text = "{Binding UserBornDate, Mode = OneWay}" DisplayDateStart="2019-01-04"/>
```

but it keeps showing 01.01.0001 when I started My app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because of the binding of the control's `Text` property to the property `UserBornDate`:

```
Text = "{Binding UserBornDate, Mode = OneWay}"
```

`DateTime` default value is `01/01/0001`, so just try to set a value to `UserBornDate`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: shouldnt make any difference...using his code sample all I had to do was add xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  for the control, but it worked... my date format is different though...

Comment: @Kixoka, the namespace is of course required to actually being able to compile the XAML in the question. After adding the namespace and successfully compiling it (including providing a binding source for the UserBornDate), you will notice that indeed `01/01/0001` will come from the binding, unless you have set the UserBornDate property to something else than its default value, as Itay pointed out here...

Comment: @elgonzo, I did both ways with the binding source and without... still works for me either way....  It doesn't show the 01/01/0001 for me at all... wierd...

Comment: @Kixoka, strange... is your binding perhaps broken? Depending on whether i set the DataContext before or after calling InitializeComponent(), i get the expected date or nothing at all with a broken binding. However, "using" a broken binding is not really useful... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo not at all... in the code behind i have "DataContext = this;" then i set the UserBorndata = some date... and run.  It shows the date value of whatever I set UserBornData to.  I created just a simple wpf app to test this.

Comment: @Kixoka, try setting UserBornData to nothing at all (i.e., let it use the default value for DateTime) (by the way, i also test it here right now ;-) )

Comment: @elgonzo I finally got it to show 01/01/0001!  lol I had to change the datatype to UserBornData to datetime.... so the OP needs to set UserBornData to current date per your post.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for last 2 days on Datepicker in XAML always showing 01-01-0001 as the default date.

I looked at many solution on Stackoverflow and elsewhere. I was not able to find a solution. Finally found an answer on MSDN.

I am not giving the complete code here but only relevant parts.

Model (GRNHeader.cs)
Nullable DateTime grnDate {get;set;}

ViewModel

```
        selectedGRN = new GRNHeader();
        selectedGRN.grnDate = DateTime.Today;
```

XAML

```
DatePicker x:Name="GRNDate" Margin="0,5,0,0" SelectedDate="{Binding selectedGRN.grnDate ,Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}"
```

works as expected.

The most important thing is to declare the bound variable to the `DatePicker` as Nullable `Datetime` in the model